# Are school proms haram?

Tags: halal-haram, school

Are secondary school proms haram?

I'm a male and have finished Yr11 and my GCSEs and have also been invited to a 'prom'. This event will involve music, dancing and halal food with no alcohol present (since we are only 15-16 yrs old).

All my other Muslim friends are going, and I've already brought my ticket. Also note that I will stay away from girls and definitely will not dance. However, if I attend then I will miss Asr and Maghrib prayers which I planned to make up after by doing Qaza.

Should I still go?

Answer (score 3):

Muslims are not allowed to attend events that involve music, singing, dancing, alcohol or the mixing of genders. The fact that we have these things everywhere in the western world doesn't make them permissible.

Allah (SWT) says:

> “And leave alone those who take their religion as play and amusement, and whom the life of this world has deceived. But remind (them) with it (the Qur’aan) lest a person be given up to destruction for that which he has earned, when he will find for himself no protector or intercessor besides Allaah” -- [al-An’aam 6:70]
>
> “And of mankind is he who purchases idle talks (i.e. music, singing) to mislead (men) from the path of Allaah without knowledge, and takes it (the path of Allaah, or the Verses of the Qur’aan) by way of mockery. For such there will be a humiliating torment (in the Hell-fire)” -- [Luqmaan 31:6]

Missing your prayer for the purpose of something that doesn't provide any real value is something that I'd definitely stay away from. Doing something for the sake Allah (SWT) has great rewards in the sight of Allah (SWT).

For more info, please refer to, https://islamqa.info/en/45789

And Allah (SWT) knows best.

Comment: I will not be attending then.

Answer (score 0):

You SHOULD never miss prayer for Stuff like this. Just cuz ur
Muslim friends are going doesn’t make it right
Be different not like the bad examples.
I suggest for celebration maybe you and ur friends
Some other day can organize maybe a trip somewhere
Like hiking, theme parks, to the beach or any other place
You like. But music, dancing is definitely haram.

Answer (score -2):

You shouldn’t go because of two things 1.you will miss prayer 2.Allah in the Quran said you shouldn’t go to proms either way